# How to center the cursor in a text input having a placeholder in Edge without JS?

Tags: css, microsoft-edge

It works in every browser except Edge. Is there a pure CSS workaround?

```css
input {
  text-align: center
}
```

```html
<input placeholder="placeholder" />
```

Comment: [This link](http://forums.asp.net/t/2065367.aspx?Microsoft+Edge+center+align+input+cursor+on+focus) does **not** help, because it provides a JS solution.

Comment: As far as I can tell, there is no pure CSS workaround for this problem.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Nice find, Tamás! This appears to be a bug with our form controls. Note that the cursor respects the instruction when there is no placeholder, but falls back to left-alignment when there is a placeholder. This seems very unintentional, and worth digging into.

Comment: is there a fix for this?

Comment: @jrode The fix has not yet landed in a stable build. When the updated bits land, I'll update this answer. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: Since no updates. 8 months of nasty bug and no updates even on the latest insider builds

Comment: I'm still seeing this. Edge 15. How has this not been addressed yet?

Comment: Still not been fixed, why anyone uses edge is beyond me

Comment: Here is the ms bug https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/4468563/

Comment: I'm still seeing this. Edge 42. How has this not been addressed yet?

Comment: 3 years later, still nothing :D

Comment: Why is this the accepted answer? It doesn't solve the problem at all...

Comment: Is there any answer to this existing Microsoft edge error? I cannot remove the placeholder and yet I want the cursor to be at the center.

Answer (score 1):

Try using this. that's the fix for edge when you already have css of input field text centered

```
 if(window.navigator.userAgent.search(/edge/ig)){

     $("#inputfield").focus((e)=>{
        $("#codefield").attr({placeholder: ""});
     });

     $("#codefield").blur((e)=>{
        $("#codefield").attr({placeholder: "Your Placeholder"});
     });

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Here is what you do to center the** `caret` **and the** `placeholder` **in an input field**

**html**

```
<input type="text" placeholder="type something..."/>
```

**style** `css`

```
input{
    text-align: center;
 }
```

**Good Luck**